# How to control child components information form main components using Prop in nuxt-property-decorator?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have been using nuxt-property-decorator in my nuxt.js projects. I want to use @Prop and control child components information from main components.

So I just want to confirm how to use that kind of decorator and make button apps. I just want push the button (its include main components) and display item information under the button.

But my app didn't work well.
Could someone give me advise about my apps? my code is below.

main component

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-btn @click="onClick" :display="showList">click</v-btn>
    <ApptestChild />
  </v-app>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "nuxt-property-decorator";
import ApptestChild from "~/components/ApptestChild.vue";

@Component({ components: { ApptestChild } })
export default class Main extends Vue {
  showList = false;
  onClick() {
    this.showList = !this.showList;
  }
}
</script>
```

child component

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <v-slot v-if="display">
      <ul>
        <li>List1</li>
        <li>List2</li>
        <li>List3</li>
      </ul>
    </v-slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from "nuxt-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class child extends Vue {
  @Prop(Boolean) display!: boolean;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you specify it didnt work well.

Comment: Just display the button. if I push the button, nothing happened.

Comment: If you start with showList = true ? I think the issue here might be with v if in v slot

Comment: I changed with showList = true, but nothing happened again.

Comment: Omg i am so blind put `:display="showList"` on your component with prop